# How to use JQuery noConflict() to load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to use JQuery noConflict() in my load page.

This is my javascript to load the page:

```
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        // initial page load
        $('#area').load('pages/home/home.php');
        $("ul.sidebar-menu li a.Dashboard").addClass("hidups");
        $('ul.sidebar-menu li a').click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            document.title = "Admin | " + page;
            $("ul.sidebar-menu li a").removeClass("hidups");
            $(this).addClass("hidups");
            $('#area').load('pages/' + page + '/' + page + '.php', '', function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == 'error') {
                    $("#area").load('pages/error/404.php');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is script on my page after load (product.php) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/alertify.core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/alertify.default.css" id="toggleCSS" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
    .modal-body2 {
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .centerd {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: static;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pages/produk/aplikasi.js"></script>

<?php
// memanggil berkas koneksi.php
require '../../config/koneksi.php';
?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
   <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
   <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
         Jammin
         <small>Data</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tables</a></li>
         <li class="active">Data Produk</li>
      </ol>
   </section>
   <!-- tempat untuk menampilkan data mahasiswa -->
   <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
               <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Data Produk</h3>
                  <a href="#myModal" id="0" class="tambah btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" style="color:black">
                  Tambah Data </a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-all">
                  <i class="icon-plus"></i> Hapus Semua Data
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="box-body">
                  <div id="data-produk"> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
<!-- awal untuk modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Tambah Data Produk</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body2">
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            <button id="simpan-produk" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Simpan Data</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But this won't work because JQuery.min has "crashed". I think I should use `jquery.noConflict` to fix it but I don't know how to use `jquery.noConflict` to my load page.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in console?

Comment: any specific reason behind using two versions of jquery lib ?

Comment: The really easy fix is to just remove jQuery 1.8.3 and use only **one** version, the latest

Comment: just add `$.noConflict();` just before this line `$(document).ready(function($) {`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of approaching this, my favourite is a closure.

```
;(function($){
    //$ is now safe here eg. $.('.selector');
})(jQuery);
```

Or

Just use $.noConflict before using the other libraries that require the dollar sign such as prototype

OR

Just use jQuery instead of $ everywhere, this will make your code less portable and less pretty :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this for jQuerynoConflict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
JQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// initial page load
        JQuery('#area').load('pages/home/home.php');
        JQuery("ul.sidebar-menu li a.Dashboard").addClass("hidups");
        JQuery('ul.sidebar-menu li a').click(function(){

        var page = JQuery(this).attr('href');
        document.title="Admin | "+page;
        JQuery("ul.sidebar-menu li a").removeClass("hidups");
        JQuery(this).addClass("hidups");  
        JQuery('#area').load('pages/'+page+'/'+ page +'.php' , '', function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == 'error') {
                    JQuery("#area").load('pages/error/404.php');
                }
            });

        return false;
        });
        }); 

</script>
```

Comment: It's `jQuery` <- lowercase *"j"*, and inside the scope of the `ready` function you'd use `$`

Comment: That's incorrect. Here you are just using 'jQuery' instead of the dollar '$' alias.